# What happens to the entropy of the pre-existing information on a black hole event horizon as more mass falls into the hole?

Tags: thermodynamics, general-relativity, black-holes, entropy, qft-in-curved-spacetime

Does the old entropy stay the same as new bits of information are added to increase the overall entropy?

Comment: It's a good question but I think any answers offered should make it clear that our knowledge of this is quite uncertain at the moment. Entropy, information, quantum fields and black holes together make a puzzle that has not been figured out.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a black hole entropy specialist. But I'm noting down some of my observations, which may be helpful for you.

[Black hole entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_hole_thermodynamics#The_third_law_2) is related to the horizon area, $A$ of that black hole: $S_{Schwarzschild~BH}^{\left(Wald\right)} = \dfrac{A}{4G_N} + + 64\pi^2c_3(\mu) + 64\pi^2\gamma \left(\log \left(4G_N^2 M^2 \mu^2 \right) − 2 + 2\gamma_E \right)$ , where $A = 16\pi~(G_NM)^2$

[Source: [Calmet, X., & Kuipers, F. $(2021)$. Quantum gravitational corrections to the entropy of a Schwarzschild black hole. Physical Review D, $104(6)$, $066012$.](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2108.06824v1)]

So if a bit of information (here I'm considering the information to be a bit of mass) is being added to a black hole, then the black hole mass and hence the horizon area will increase (according to the [$2^{nd}$ law of black hole mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_hole_thermodynamics#The_second_law_2)). So obviously, black hole entropy will increase.

Forget about the quantum corrections in the BH entropy for the time being (and for the easiness of the calculation and to have a physical intuition):

Let $m$ amount of "radially in-falling" mass (or information) has been added to a Schwarzschild BH of initial mass $M$. So BH mass will then be $M+m$ .

$\therefore S_{BH}^{new} = 4\pi G_N (M+m)^2$ , while $S_{BH}^{old} = 4\pi G_N M^2$ .

Hence, $S_{BH}^{new} \approx S_{BH}^{old} \left(1+\dfrac{2m}{M}\right)$ .

So the entropy has been changed, as we have seen from the simple-most consideration.